# How can I restore my app data if I manually pulled it out before resetting and reinstalling my phone?

Tags: applications, adb, backup, restore

Yesterday I was stuck in this awkward situation where my Moto G with Cyanogenmod 12.1 got stuck in the boot animation after recent restart. It was working fine for a month or two before that.

Based on my limited knowledge and friend's suggestion I decided that simply factory resetting and reinstalling the OS through the custom recovery will work fine and keep my media as well (and it did). The thing is I really wanted to keep some of my app data but backup feature through `adb` wouldn't work because as I understood you need to confirm it on your phone which was bricked at the time.
I then pulled the data folder with all the app data into my pc and proceeded.

The thing is I have no idea how to restore it now, I could have screwed up somewhere. Pasting what I saved up back into my phone won't do anything.

How can I restore my app data now?

Comment: Could you give a few more details on your "pasting back" process? What files and folders did you put where, how did you do that? Picking an "easy example" would help. Hint: I'd recommend "pasting back" while the device is booted into recovery. Also make sure owner and permissions match (files/folders must be owned by the corresponding app with r/w for the owner and the group at least r, often also r/w). If you "pulled" the data to a Windows PC, all permission info is probably lost (unless you archived it before on the device using e.g. `tar`).